# Mime/Encoding issue from uploading files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, formidable

I'm having a weird issue I can't quite tease apart. My scenario is that I capture from the camera an image and display it on the web page for someone to preview. If they like it, then they hit upload, and it passes it to the backend to save.

Here's the stack - node on both sides:

- Front end: Vue.js

```js
// Need to convert the dataURL in the canvas element to a File object for uploading
function dataURLtoFile(dataUrl: string, fileName: string): File {
  var arr = dataUrl.split(",");
  var first_arr = arr[0]
  var match_arr = first_arr?.match(/:(.*?);/);
  var mime = 'image/png'
  if ((match_arr) && (match_arr?.length > 0)) {
    mime = match_arr[1];
  }
  var bstr = atob(arr[1]);
  var n = bstr.length;
  var u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
  while (n--) {
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }
  return new File([u8arr], fileName, { type: mime });
}

// Cut out some elements to make it cleaner
function submitInfo() {
      let formData = new FormData();

      const imageDataUrl = (document?.getElementById("canvas_image") as HTMLCanvasElement).toDataURL();

      const objectPicture = dataURLtoFile(imageDataUrl, uuid());

      formData.append('objectPicture', objectPicture);
      axios.post("/api/upload", formData);
}
```

- Back end: Express

```js
app.post("/api/upload", async (req, res) => {
 
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  var metadataFile = null;
  var objectPicture = null;
  await form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    // The name for our upload includes a prefix we can use to identify our files later
    const uploadName = [uuid() + "." + mime.extension(files.objectPicture.mimetype),
    ].join("|");

    var objectPicture = new File(
      fs.readFileSync(files.objectPicture.filepath, 'utf8'),
      uploadName,
      {
        type: files.objectPicture.mimetype,
      }
    );

  });
});
```

So not much there - but when i look at the file, vs the original, it's all just digits (vs. what I assume is proper encoding). What did I get wrong?

---

Edit: Updated readFileSync with 'utf8' and no change :(
Also, looked at the temp file on disk that formidable saved, and it looks fine. So it's something in my code reading it back in that seems to be messing it up!

Comment: Add `utf8` as the second parameter to readFileSync

Comment: Tried this, and no joy :(. Updated the code above.

Comment: When I work with canvas I use the function `element.toBlob()` and add this blob to a file. Just if "canvas_image" is really a `<canvas>` element.

Comment: canvas_image _is_ an image, so i could certainly do this. however, this code was working as is when all operating in the client, and the size of the object is correct on the server, so i don't think that's the problem. happy to try though.